# MVC - Is it necessary to create one more db-layer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As we know, architecture should be separated to layers such View layer, DB layer, etc.

Each part should be independent from other and can be replaced without changing other layers. For example, we have a standard ASP.NET MVC application with MS SQL as database. This application uses Entity Framework. So, we have a special classes for View - View Classes.

These classes manage displaying and getting information from front-end. Also, we have model classes, which includes LINQ requests to Entity Framework generated classes (EF Model), updating, inserting methods etc. And we have thick controllers, where we just validate data from front-end and call methods from model classes.

In this place I have qualm... Are model classes necessary or not?

If we don't use Entity Framework then of course, we need this layer because we can't write SQL requests directly in controller (otherwise we do our controllers depend on logical DB schema), but we use Entity Framework and Entity Framework is already conceptual model!

It means, that we should "convert" logical DB structure (Schema of DB) to our conceptual models. In this case where should be LINQ to Entity requests for example? Directly inside controllers? What is right approach?

Some examples:

Approach View-Controller-Model-EF Model

View class :

```
    public class VacancyFormViewModel
    {
        // swap is should be null and should be created manually if necessary
        public VacancyFormViewModel()
        {
            Site = new ListViewModel();
            Surgeon = new ListViewModel();
            Reason = new ListViewModel();
        }

        public int? ID { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime SurgeryDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Site")]
        public ListViewModel Site { get; set; }
        public TimePartViewModel StartTime { get; set; }
        public TimePartViewModel EndTime { get; set; }
....
```

EF Model class (generated by Entity Framework):

```
    public partial class Vacancy
    {
        public Vacancy()
        {
            this.Swaps = new HashSet<Swap>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime SurgeryDate { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime NotifyDate { get; set; }
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
.....
```

Model class (in Save method is shown an action to "copy" data from model class to EF-model class:

```
    public class Vacancy
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime SurgeryDate { get; set; }
        public int StartTime { get; set; }
        public int EndTime { get; set; }
.....

        public void Save()
        {
            VTS.EFModels.Vacancy ef_vacancy;
            if (!ID.HasValue)
                ef_vacancy = new EFModels.Vacancy();
            else
                ef_vacancy = (from i in _db.Vacancies where i.ID == ID.Value select i).FirstOrDefault();
            ef_vacancy.DecisionID = DecisionEnum;
            ef_vacancy.EndTime = new TimeSpan(EndTime, 0, 0);
            ef_vacancy.Notes = Notes;
            ef_vacancy.NotifyDate = NotifyDate;
            ef_vacancy.ReasonID = ReasonID;
            ef_vacancy.SiteID = SiteID;
            ef_vacancy.StartTime = new TimeSpan(StartTime, 0, 0);
......
```

and controller (a "bridge" between View class and Model class)

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VacancyForm(VacancyFormViewModel model)
        {
            Vacancy v = new Vacancy();

            v.ID = model.ID;
            v.SurgeryDate = model.SurgeryDate;
            v.SurgeonID = surgeonSelected.Item2;
            v.ReasonID = int.Parse(model.Reason.SelectedItem);
            v.SiteID = int.Parse(model.Site.SelectedItem);
            v.DecisionEnum = model.Decision;
            v.NotifyDate = model.NotifyDate;
            v.SurgeryDate = model.SurgeryDate;
            v.StartTime = int.Parse(model.StartTime.SelectedItem);
            v.EndTime = int.Parse(model.EndTime.SelectedItem);
.....
            v.Save();
.....
```

It works, but is it not reduntant?

Maybe discard model class at all and write all actions with EF directly in controller?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using an Entity Framework model in your views.  Generally this translation layer between two kinds of models is used when there's view-specific logic being placed in the model or if there's any kind of impedance mis-match between the view and the model.

Comment: No it's not redundant. VacancyFormViewModel has no dependencies. Vacancy however is dependent on EntityFramework. So by using Vacancy you've now made your Presentation layer dependent on EF as well. This makes no sense in the light of your comments re: it's bad to make a controller make direct Sql calls but somehow you're happy if it's dependent on EF? Even in a thick controller, a dependency is a dependency. You can use Repository pattern to decouple from EF but by then using Vacancy, you re-tether yourself to EF. This tight coupling means all related unit tests are now, not, unit tests.

Comment: @rism Do you suggest that we always use a ViewModel version of each Model even though the ViewModel would be just a copy of the Model? I was also wondering if it's not redundant, either. For instance, if I decorate model / entity properties with let's say complex regular expression and I need to change something, then I'd have to change the same property "decorator" in two places. I am not experienced and I might be missing something here but this is how i think it might be redundant.

Comment: @ZikO The scenario you've presented is not the one in the OPs question. I could give you 50 ways in which not reusing data layer models is redundant and 1 in which it's not. That doesn't mean that 50 ways wins, if the lifetime cost of absorbing the 1, is greater than time saved on the 50. These are not questions with perfectly neat answers, they are choices. What I've said is that you cannot achieve the same outcome as using  VacancyFormViewModel by reusing Vacancy therefore it's not redundant. They end up being two completely different applications in terms of cost, test, maintainability etc.

Comment: I think MS indetended EF to the the M in MVC and you can do it without a seperate Model class. However. if your models end up depending on EF you cant use them in mobile apps

Comment: as to whether you need a VM, that's a seperate question, but I say yes you always do. although it might start off looking exactly like your model, you'll find it soon gets more complicated, validation errors, extra header info on the page etc

Comment: @rism TBH I am progressing slowly but still beginner. My question is simply related to your argument regarding dependency to EF. I am familiar with Rep and interested to have application in my project. Frankly, I did not find anything about VacancyFormViewModel and Vacancy that they are completely different applications in your previous comment. Not saying it's not there, though. Perhaps there is 50 other scenarios or ways but I am not yet experience to imagine them. I am afraid your answer does not really help me. I guess because of little experience in applying MVC.

Comment: @Ziko Vacancy has this: ef_vacancy = (from i in _db.Vacancies where i.ID == ID.Value select i).FirstOrDefault(); VacancyViewModel does not. The _db is a DataContext which equals an EF dependency and all that that entails.